# How to close browser window with AS2

Tags: javascript, actionscript-2

I was put on a project written in AS2. Yeah, I know it's 2016. Don't ask.

It's a Flash popup game. I am trying to close the popup window from within the game at the end of the game and I am wondering if that's even possible anymore in any of the browsers past IE6. I have tried:

```
getURL("javascript:self.close();");

getURL("javascript:window.close();");
```

As well as writing a JS function "CloseWindow" in the HTML wrapper of the game that invokes window.close() and then calling that function from within the Flash game with

```
getURL("javascript:CloseWindow();");
```

I also made sure that "allowScriptAccess" is set to "always" in the html wrapper.

I read that those techniques used to work in older browsers but the security settings in new browser don't allow them to work anymore.

So is there a way to close browser windows from within flash content in current browsers?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?345832-Close-Browser-Window)

Comment: @ChetanJadhavCD That's AS3. As stated in both the title and the body of my question, I'm working in AS2. As far as I can see, there's nothing in that article that can be transposed to AS2 that would work.

Comment: As @ChetanJadhavCD mentioned, the answer is clear. You should use `ExternalInterface.call("javascript:window.close();");` as `flash.external.ExternalInterface` class is available in AS2.